# Equal width flex items regardless of content length

Tags: html, css, width, flexbox

The flexboxes in my code below look fantastic, but I am confused how the box widths are determined.

For instance, if you delete what is written in the `<p>` or `class="card_title"` elements, the size of the box also changes.

*Is there a way to set all the boxes to be the same width regardless of the lengths of the titles or paragraphs?*

[**codepen demo**](http://codepen.io/mcraiganthony/pen/NxGxqm?editors=1100)

```css
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  color: #696969;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn--block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.cards {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cards__item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
}
@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  .cards__item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 56rem) {
  .cards__item {
    width: 33.3333%;
  }
}
.card {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px -14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card:hover .card__image {
  -webkit-filter: contrast(100%);
  filter: contrast(100%);
}
.card__content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.card__image {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
  -webkit-filter: contrast(70%);
  filter: contrast(70%);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.43, 0.41, 0.22, 0.91);
  transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.43, 0.41, 0.22, 0.91);
  transition: filter 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.43, 0.41, 0.22, 0.91);
  transition: filter 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.43, 0.41, 0.22, 0.91), -webkit-filter 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.43, 0.41, 0.22, 0.91);
}
.card__image::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}
@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  .card__image::before {
    padding-top: 66.6%;
  }
}
.card__image--wedding {
  background-image: url(wedding2.png);
}
.card__image--baby {
  background-image: url(baby2.png);
}
.card__image--moving {
  background-image: url(moving2.png);
}
.card__image--graduation {
  background-image: url(graduation2.png);
}
.card__image--retirement {
  background-image: url(retirement2.png);
}
.card__image--award {
  background-image: url(trophy2.png);
}
.card__title {
  color: #696969;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.card__text {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="life_events">
  <hr class="section-heading-spacer"></hr>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <h2 class="section-heading">Moments That Matter</h2>
  <ul class="cards">
    <li class="cards__item">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image card__image--wedding"></div>
        <div class="card__content">
          <div class="card__title">Getting Married</div>
          <p class="card__text"></p>
          <button class="btn btn--block card__btn">Let's Go</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="cards__item">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image card__image--baby"></div>
        <div class="card__content">
          <div class="card__title">Growing Your Family</div>
          <p class="card__text"></p>
          <button class="btn btn--block card__btn">Let's Go</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="cards__item">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image card__image--moving"></div>
        <div class="card__content">
          <div class="card__title">Moving to a New Home</div>
          <p class="card__text"></p>
          <button class="btn btn--block card__btn">Let's Go</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="cards__item">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image card__image--graduation"></div>
        <div class="card__content">
          <div class="card__title">Requesting Tuition Reimbursement</div>
          <p class="card__text"></p>
          <button class="btn btn--block card__btn">Let's Go</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="cards__item">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image card__image--retirement"></div>
        <div class="card__content">
          <div class="card__title">Preparing for Retirement/Separation</div>
          <p class="card__text"></p>
          <button class="btn btn--block card__btn">Let's Go</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="cards__item">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__image card__image--award"></div>
        <div class="card__content">
          <div class="card__title">Awarding an Employee</div>
          <p class="card__text"></p>
          <button class="btn btn--block card__btn">Let's Go</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a way to set all the boxes to be the same width regardless of the lengths of the titles or paragraphs?

You currently have no defined width on your `card` elements. This means the width of each element will be set by its content (`.card_image`, `.card_content`. `.card_title`, etc.).

If you want the width of these elements to be uniform and fixed, then give them a width. Try this:

```
.card { flex: 0 0 100%; } /* don't grow, don't shrink, take full width of parent */
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORKRjG?editors=1100)

Comment: amazing, thanks so much!  I have a follow up question to this, at full width this definitely fixed the problem.  However I noticed when I start shrinking the browser window, the width sizing issue reappears.  What element would I have to change to fix the responsiveness of those boxes?

Comment: There are several media queries in your code defining a width for `.cards__item`, the parent of `.card`. On screen width 56rem+, `.cards__item` has `width: 33.3333%`. As the screen re-sizes smaller, a media query for screen width 40rem+ kicks in, adjusting the element to `width: 50%`. This is all good because the child (`.card`) is set in my answer to take 100% of the parent width.

Comment: However, when the screen size gets even smaller, there is no width defined for `cards__item`, so our answer doesn't work. You need to define a width for this element. [**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORKRjG?editors=1100)

Comment: can't thank you enough.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around this code, but this certainly clears up a lot.  thanks again.